# Issue while building apache superset using docker

Tags: apache-superset

Am getting the error while building apache superset project cloned from "git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git"
"Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh": stat /app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh: input/output error: unknown"

Trying to run apache superset locally using docker